# How to convert any date time to microseconds in perl

Tags: perl

I need convert any given date or datetime to microseconds using perl. I tried  the following code it works only for the current time you run it.

```
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my $timestamp = int (gettimeofday * 1000);
print STDOUT "timestamp = $timestamp\n";
```

I am wondering if there a way to convert any given date or datetime into microseconds in perl, how? 
btw, I don't have Parse module installed. my perl version is v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi.

Comment: http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/58079418600/plenv-alternative-for-perlbrew

Comment: I’m just commenting since I have no code for you. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) is a core module and you could do your 1000 * op after you convert a date (probably with `strptime`) to `->epoch`.

Comment: @Ashley Time::Piece is in the module core as of perl 5.9.5;

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` can do that easily:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new( year => 2012, nanosecond => 4 );
print $dt->hires_epoch();
```

For more examples see [the docs on cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm)

Comment: Thanks Tom. But, unfortunately,   I got "Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC" when I ran your code. My server is a prod server I can't install anything on it.

Comment: Consider installing (in your HOME directory) [prelbrew](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew).  It provides an isolated environment from the system-installed Perl into which you can safely add your own modules.

Comment: @Gary If your server doesn't have basic libraries such as DateTime, consider switching to a different provider... Alternatively, just unpackage the modules in some folder and then `use lib "/path/to/folder";` which will allow you to use the libraries in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to convert any given date to microseconds. That is, using system date function like below code snippet .
suppose I want to convert a date of 100 days ago to microseconds.

```
my $anydate = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime( time -  100 * 24 * 60 * 60 ); # a date of 100 days ago;
my $microsecs = `date -d "$anydate"  +%s%N | cut -b1-13`;
print "$microsecs\n";
```

This really works in any perl version without installing any module.